# Create XML using LINQ-to-XML API

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to create an XML which looks like

```
<Records FileUniqueId="1234567" Source="CCC">
  <Record InfNumber="122354" AgencyNumber="017"></Record>
  <Record InfNumber="122355" AgencyNumber="018"></Record>
 <Record InfNumber="122356" AgencyNumber="018"></Record>
</Records>
XElement responseXML = new XElement("Records");
                responseXML.SetAttributeValue(BusinessConstants.colFileUniqueID, _fileUniqueId);
                responseXML.SetAttributeValue(BusinessConstants.colSourceName, _sourceName);

                foreach (InfringementEntity ie in iLES.infringementEntities)
                {
                    responseXML.Add(new XElement("Record"));
                    XElement record = responseXML.Element("Record");

                    record.SetAttributeValue(BusinessConstants.colInfringementNumber, ie.infringementNumber);
                    record.SetAttributeValue(BusinessConstants.colIssueAgency, ie.issueAgency);
                }
```

I am using the above code to generate the XML, but the issue is that when I am setting the attributes for a Record, it overwrites the attributes of 1st record everytime.

So the XML I am getting is:

```
 <Records FileUniqueId="1234567" Source="CCC">
     <Record InfNumber="122356" AgencyNumber="018"></Record>
      <Record/>
      <Record/>
    </Records>
```

please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's overwriting the attributes of the first record because you're *telling* it to - you're not using the Record element you've just created. You could do it like this:

```
foreach (InfringementEntity ie in iLES.infringementEntities)
{
    XElement newRecord = new XElement("Record");
    newRecord.SetAttributeValue(BusinessConstants.colInfringementNumber,
                                ie.infringementNumber);
    newRecord.SetAttributeValue(BusinessConstants.colIssueAgency,
                                responseXML.Add(newRecord);
}
```

... but there are rather more idiomatic ways of doing it, such as:

```
XElement responseXML = new XElement("Records",
    iLes.infringementEntities.Select(ie => new XElement("Record",
        new XAttribute(BusinessConstants.colInfringementNumber,
                       ie.infringementNumber),
        new XAttribute(BusinessConstants.colIssueAgency, ie.issueAgency))));
```

That replaces the *whole* of your code, including the `foreach` statement.